# C# Graphics.DrawImage alters my colors

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm using [Image Resizing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11143/Image-Resizing-outperform-GDI) to up and downscale icons but I'm noticing some color changes/alterations when I'm drawing it. The problem is not with the filters since I've checked the image output and it looks fine by itself.

Here's an example: left is how it should look like, right is what I see in my application.
[image: Color alteration]

I've created a custom ToolStripItem and I'm drawing in its OnPaint function.
The code I'm using for drawing looks like this.

```
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image,
                new Rectangle(
                    new Point(Width / 2 - IconSize / 2, Height / 2 - IconSize / 2),
                    new Size(IconSize, IconSize)));
```

---

**Update:** I have set the PixelOffsetMode to Half and that fixes the cutout pixels you see in the above example but the colors are still off and it messes with the transparency. Left is the icon I have saved using its Save function and placed it on top of a screenshot of the icon that's being drawn with the above.

Also a note that this is using a different filter, hence why it doesn't like anything like the above.

[image]

Comment: The screen shot doesn't look like a ToolStripItem.  Are you clearing the canvas before you draw?  The posted code doesn't look real: a variable named  `Image`?

Comment: I've checked the link you provided, and looks like either it's an expected deviation (sample inputs & outputs there also dont seem to be totally equal) or you're not doing it correct (code you provided is not verbose enough)

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried clearing but it doesn't change anything. And yes, I'm resizing the icon and assigning it to the Image property of the ToolStripItem and use that to draw the image myself.

Comment: @ArturUdod I've already checked what it outputs and the image gets resized correctly and the colors look like it should. The colors change when I'm drawing it for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried `SmoothingMode.None` and `PixelOffsetMode.None`? It looks to me like something that would happen because of antialiasing.

Comment: @vesan I just tried tried that and there was no visible change.

Comment: The right part looks more reddish, but: I don't think I trust your example image. Photoshop does not show those cut-off semi-height pixels I see on the left part at the top and bottom. So I think you have done some patching to prepare the example. - The effect looks to me like a problem with color profiles. You should try to investigate in that direction...!

Comment: @TaW The left side is in fact the image I saved using the Save call after resizing it. I didn't touch it up. The right-side does cut out some pixels, but I just set the PixelOffsetMode to half and that seems to have fixed that, but the colors are still off.

Comment: The Graphics.InterpolationMode property matters.  Default is Bilinear, the left one resembles Bicubic.